# Python Virtual Environment Help - Django

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Error Message

[image: 1]

I am struggling to install Django to my new project using pipenv, it keeps telling me to run another virtual environment rather than actually installing Django.

I tried to do what it says to using the other virtual env but it still won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You get that all wrong.
"The venv module supports creating lightweight “virtual environments”, each with their own independent set of Python packages installed in their site directories. A virtual environment is created on top of an existing Python installation, known as the virtual environment’s “base” Python, and may optionally be isolated from the packages in the base environment, so only those explicitly installed in the virtual environment are available.

When used from within a virtual environment, common installation tools such as pip will install Python packages into a virtual environment without needing to be told to do so explicitly."

pip is python package manager and there for tool for installing modules such as Django. If you are running linux you can use following commands

```
-> cd storefront
-> python -m venv venv  (create new virtual environment name: "venv")
-> . venv/bin/activate  (to activate virtual environment) 
-> pip install django   (to install Django modules)
```